# D3.js V4 image not shown on safari, when trying to implement pan and zoom feature

Tags: javascript, d3.js, safari

I am trying to implement panning and zooming feature using d3.js, everything is working fine, but when I try to run the same code on Safari the image is not displayed.

The recreation of the issue (Please run it in safari):

```js
let imgHeight = 400, imgWidth = 900,
    width =  900, height = 450;

let zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed);

let svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  width + "px")
    .attr("height", height + "px");

svg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,25)")
    .call(zoom)
    .append("g");

svg.append("image")
    .attr("width",  imgWidth + "px")
    .attr("height", imgHeight + "px")
    .attr("href", "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg");

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

```html
<div id='canvas'>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to change attribute `href` in image tag as `xlink:href`, now it's working fine.

```js
let imgHeight = 400, imgWidth = 900,
    width =  900, height = 450;

let zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed);

let svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  width + "px")
    .attr("height", height + "px");

svg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,25)")
    .call(zoom)
    .append("g");

svg.append("image")
    .attr("width",  imgWidth + "px")
    .attr("height", imgHeight + "px")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg");

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

```html
<div id='canvas'>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```